# Import large files with Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to import lot of big files with Mathematica to perform NonlinearModelFit after that. So, I used Import function as it is described below :

```
files = FileNames["*.dat"];  
data = Parallelize[Import[#, "Table"] & /@ files]
```

The problem is that this step is very.. very.. slow.
Do you have any ideas to improve this part ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ReadList[#, String]&/@files
```

or

```
ReadList[#, Record]&/@files
```

Further to the OP's comment, there are various ways to access a column, for example.

```
dataAsStrings = ReadList[#, String]&/@files;
flatterData = Flatten[dataAsStrings, 1];
splitData = StringSplit[#] & /@ flatterData;
column2 = splitData[[All, 2]];
```

Then perhaps use `ToExpression` to convert strings to numerical values.

Comment: Ok. @Chris Degnen Thank you for your answer. It is much .. much .. faster !!! But, how can I use a specific column ? I mean I want to use NonlinearModelFit with data a specific column. Can you help me with that point ?